# Inline HTML5 SVG filters without interfering with the layout

Tags: html, svg

I need to inject the following inline SVG filter into my HTML5 document:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="grayscale">
            <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0">
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

I tried placing it outside of the `<html>` tags but this did not work. It leaves a large blank space at the start or end of the displayed page depending on where I put it.

I tried placing it in the `<head>` or start of the `<body>` tag but this leaves a large blank space at the start of the displayed document as well.

Setting `display: none;` on the SVG object will prevent the filter from working.

I have also tried setting `<svg>`'s `width` and `height` properties to zero but this only works if I set the CSS for svg objects to `display: block;`.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <svg> ... </svg>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

Currently, my temporary fix is to use css to try to hide it:

```
svg {
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

How do I prevent the SVG object from interfering with my HTML layout (without using this css trick)?

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EvFrX/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive this works, but SVG elements allow width and height attributes (like `img` tags). So try with: `svg width="0" height="0"`

Comment: Note: this worked for me when the SVG element's CSS `display` was set to `block`.