# SVG filter artifacts when removing CSS property

Tags: html, css, svg

**Context**

I am working on a browser extension, [Night Video Tuner](https://github.com/PyvesB/NightVideoTuner), which injects SVG filters into HTML pages using Javascript, in order to filter out blue light from videos. Here is an example of what an SVG filter generated by the extension would look like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="temperature_filter" style="display: none;">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.6949030005552019 0 0 0 0 0 0.4310480202110507 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

`style="display: none;"` is used to prevent the SVG element from affecting the layout of the page.

I am adding a `filter: url(#temperature_filter)` property to the style attribute of any video element found in the current HTML page in order to apply this SVG filter to the media content. Here is a small [Fiddle showcasing a similar setup](https://jsfiddle.net/Pyves/fyy5wrkw/), with a video and its filter applied to it.

**Issue**

So far this approach is working like a charm on Chrome and Opera. Unfortunately, due to a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1306960), I cannot use the `style="display: none;"` property for that browser and am looking into applying workarounds suggested by this [other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926668/inline-html5-svg-filters-without-interfering-with-the-layout) instead.

I noticed that the overall quality of the SVG filter is significantly degraded in Firefox, with visual artifacts appearing, especially in darker parts of the video. This is also the case when I remove `style="display: none;"` from the filter in Opera and Chrome, which suggests that this property is linked to the filter no longer rendering properly. Here is an example, with on the left hand side the filter without `style="display: none;"`, and on the right hand side the filter with the property, resulting in a much stronger and smoother filter:

[image: Filters]

I am using the latest version of Opera, Firefox and Chrome on Windows, and this happens regardless of hardware acceleration being enabled or not.

**Questions**

- Why does the absence of `style="display: none;"` cause the filter to
  be rendered so poorly?
- Is there any workaround to render the filter correctly in Firefox, as
  `style="display: none;"` cannot be used with it in this context?

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVG, filters are supposed to be using the Linear RGB colour space by default.  However it appears as if Chrome is hardwired to using the sRGB colour space when fi;ltering `<video>` elements.  I'm not sure why - it's possibly/probably a bug.

You can get Firefox to behave the same as Chrome, by specifying

```
color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
```

on your filter.  Unfortunately, Chrome ignores you if you try to force it to use the LinearRGB colour space (`color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB"`).

And you can hide your SVG filter in the page by specifying a zero width and height on the `<svg>` element.

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 488px; height: 360px; filter: url(#temperature_filter)">
</video>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="temperature_filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.694 0 0 0 0 0 0.431 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fyy5wrkw/8/

Comment: Thanks, `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` fixes the poor rendering in Firefox! I guess using `display: none` somehow forces sRGB in Chrome/Opera? As far as hiding the SVG is concerned, the layout is still affected in some cases with your suggestion. For instance in the Youtube autoplay transition, a thin black rectangle shifts the layout towards the bottom (http://images.jupload.fr/1505154323.png). Any idea why?

Comment: Normally it isn't a problem. But if it is affecting you, just add `position: absolute` and shift it off the page. Eg. `left: -999`