# Embedding an SVG filter in an HTML document

Tags: html, svg

Is there any way to embed an SVG `filter` element in an HTML document, so that it can be applied to SVG and HTML elements (via CSS) at some point? The problem with putting it inside an `svg` element which is itself embedded in the HTML document is that the `svg` element itself takes up space, which is undesirable.

Comment: You may put the svg element at the bottom of your page. Then you give the `svg{position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;}` At least this is what they are doing at css-tricks.com checking what others are doing is always a good idea

Comment: @enxaneta Interesting, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try it like this:

- Wrap the `svg` in the`div`
- For `div`, assign the css property`position: absolute;`which will
  output it from the general stream and will not interfere with the
  markup
- hide the `div`
- In `CSS`, apply a filter by its`id` to any other HTML `markup object

  `filter:url(#nameID);`

**Update:**

I have to mention some of the nuances of using the `display: none;`

Here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46142733/7394871) the problems of applying SVG filters in various browsers are discussed in detail.

@Paul LeBeau in its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46143732/7394871) recommends using SVG `width = "0"`and `height = "0"` instead of `display: none;`

Below is the code from his answer.

```html
<video autoplay controls muted src=" https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" style="width: 488px; height: 360px; filter: url(#temperature_filter)">
</video>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="temperature_filter" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 0.694 0 0 0 0 0 0.431 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

As written in the comments @enxaneta is better to use:

```
svg{position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Slightly hacky, one might say though... is there "officially endorsed" method? I suppose not...

Comment: @Noldorin I added an example

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful elaboration. Although maybe this isn't a super-clean solution, I'm confident it's the best one around (indeed, I tried the `display: none` tactic myself and the filter didn't even render)... so I'll gladly accept the answer.

Comment: @Noldorin And I was glad to help you. Answering you and I learned some nuances.